# golang regexp find matching strings

Tags: regex, go

I have strings of the format `%s/%s/%s:%s` where there are four substrings. The first three substrings are separated by a `/` and the last one by a `:`. I want to extract the individual sub-strings. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(".*/.*/.*:.*")
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllStringSubmatch("a/b/c-c:d", -1))
}
```

In the above program I wanted: `a`, `b`, `c-c` and `d` to be printed as individual elements. But I am not able to extract the individual fields. The entire string is returned as the first element of the array that `FindAllStringSubmatch` returns. What is the way to extract the individual elements that match the regex ?

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/M1sKGl0n2tK

Comment: Do you mean using 4 groups? `([^/:]+)/([^/:]+)/([^/:]+):([^/:]+)` https://regex101.com/r/9trHtP/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split as it's pattern is fixed you know it's `:` separated then `/` separated regex is expensive CPU process

```
parts := strings.Split("a/b/c-c:d", ":")
fmt.Println(strings.Split(parts[0], "/"), parts[1])
```

& if you prefer using regex then also use full match `^` at the beginning & `$` at the end

```
"^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+):([^:]+)$"
```

e.g this will not match `"a/a/b/c-c:d"` but will match `"a/b/c-c:d"`

Answer (score 1):

Use captured group to extract individual strings.
Try below regex to match the string and use $1,$2,$3,$4 to get individual strings matched.

```regex
(.+)/(.+)/(.+):(.+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0WAiv/1)